# Unable to pass array of integers to asp.net webapi from angular 7 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an array of integer values to the server webapi endpoint via my angular 7 application getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds method. For some reason the endpoint is receiving null value. I have tried several ways but the parameter of the endpoint is null. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong

Component

```
  export interface IDocumentIds {
    ids: number[];
    }

          documentIds: IDocumentIds = <IDocumentIds>{};


          this.documentUploadService.createDocumentUpload(this.documents)
                    .then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            this.documentIds.ids = Object.keys(result).map(k => result[k]);
                            console.log(this.documentIds);
                            this.getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(this.documentIds);
                            this.setGridOptions();
                            this.setColumns();
                            this.notify.success('Documents uploaded Successfully');
                        }
                    }).catch(err => {
                        this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While uploading the documents');
                    });

 public getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds) {
        if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
            this.Loading = true;

            this.initGrid();
            this.documentUploadService.getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds)
            .then((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    this.DocumentUploadDetails = data;
                    this.Loading = false;
                    this.notify.success('Documents uploaded Successfully');
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While uploading the documents');
            });
        }
    }
```

Service

```
     getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds: IDocumentIds) {
                    return this.mgr360CommonService.httpGetByKey('/api/documentupload/detailsByIds' ,  documentIds);
                  }      

const httpPostOptions = {

    headers:
        new HttpHeaders(
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            }),

    withCredentials: true,
};

        httpGetByKey(url: string, key: any) {

            return this.httpClient.get(this.webApiLocation + url + '/' + key, httpPostOptions)
                .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
                    return response;
                }))
                .toPromise()
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    this.onError(error);
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
        }
```

asp.net web api
    model

```
  public class DocumentIdViewModel
    {
       public int[] ids;
    }
```

Endpoint

```
 [HttpGet]
            [Route("api/documentupload/detailsByIds/{id}")]
            public IHttpActionResult DetailsByIds(DocumentIdViewModel documentIds)
            {
                var viewModel = GetDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds);
                return Ok(viewModel);
            }
```

I have also tried setting the parameter to int array of the web method

From angular

```
this.getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(this.documentIds.ids);
```

On server

```
 public IHttpActionResult DetailsByIds(int[] documentIds)
        {
            var viewModel = GetDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds);
            return Ok(viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: could you show  class `DocumentIdViewModel documentIds`?

Comment: I think it is already in the post  public class DocumentIdViewModel
    {
       public int[] ids;
    }

Comment: Have you seen that you are actually sending `id's` in `Request Payload` - see this in your browser?

Comment: in my browser console i can see http://localhost:56888/api/documentupload/detailsByIds/[object%20Object]

Comment: if i am passing array only from angular then i can see http://localhost:56888/api/documentupload/detailsByIds/123,124,125

Comment: please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing your `ids` in body, then add `[FromBody]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DetailsByIds([FromBody] int[] documentIds)
{
}
```

Otherwise if you send your IDs in URI:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DetailsByIds([FromUri] int[] documentIds)
{
}
```

**UPDATE:**
In order to get enumerated parameters, then you should create the following query string:

```
localhost:56888/api/documentupload/DetailsByIds?
    detailsByIds=123&detailsByIds124&detailsByIds125
```

There is a great article about parameters at MSDN [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

You can use `HttpParams` class to create parameters. As your parameter name is the same, then you can create a loop. This is a way to pass URL arguments to HTTP request:

```
import { HttpParams, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('var1', val1);
params = params.append('var2', val2);

this.http.get(StaticSettings.BASE_URL, {params: params}).subscribe(...);
```

[Angular docs about passing parameters to HTTP requst.](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

**UPDATE 1:**

Let me show an example how it is possible to add params:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let params = new HttpParams();
array.forEach(id => {
  params.append('detailsByIds', id);
});
```

Comment: I tried both [FromUri] int[] documentIds and [FromBody] int[] documentIds and both didnt work

Comment: How do I create that enumerated parameters ?

Comment: Shouldnt i be creating that in angular side

Comment: in the example you have shared it shows fixed parameters. In my case it could be several values. If I am passing an object then it should be only one parameter right

Comment: I am getting error http://localhost:56888/api/documentupload/detailsByIds/[object%20Object]?var1=%5Bobject%20Object%5D  Unauthorized

Comment: I did this  let params = new HttpParams();
        var parameter = url.split('/', 5);
      
        params = params.append('var1', parameter[4]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196137/discussion-between-tom-and-stepup).

Comment: the value is still null